Crop image (Translate and scale)
I want to reproduce the same crop results which I am getting in the crop tool in flutter on the web (with basic html and css).
I have built a crop tool in flutter (not actually cropping the image). This crop tool uses the scale value, translateX, and translateY value to crop an image. I then use the transform widget to scale and translate the images accordingly. The widget is as follows.
FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.identity()
              ..scale(scale)
              ..translate(translateX, translateY!),
            child: RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: quarterTurns!,
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: imageWidth!,
                height: imageHeight!,
                memCacheWidth: 650,
                placeholder: (context, str) => Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Loading...',
                    style: AppFonts.satoshiNormalStyle(
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontColor: AppColors.black,
                      height: 1.2,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                imageUrl: imagePath,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )


I am getting the desired results from the crop tool in flutter. However when I try to use the scale, translateX and translateY values on the web it isnt giving me the accurate result.
The HTML and CSS I am using is as follows.
HTML CODE :-
    <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="IMAGE_PATH"
                alt="Image" class="image">
        </div>
    </div>

CSS CODE :-
.outer-container {
margin: auto;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 600px;
height: 506px;
border: solid 2px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;

}

.container {

    width: 500px;
    height: 406px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.image {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: scale(scale) translate(translateX (in px) , tranlateY (in px));

}

I want to get the desired output on the web, so that the image looks same across the flutter app and the web site.

are you sure about transform-origin: top left; coordonates ?

I tried keeping it default, but top left was giving me a better result !! What do you suggest ?

I was asking because FittedBox(..) did not seem to reset transform-origin.  What is your browser inspector is telling you aboiy the style applied , is similar to what you try to set ?
